# Creating a function from known data and variable relationships

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I'm developing a game and I need to create a predictable function while most of the variables are not 100% under my control. I will explain the practical situation:

You have two characters, trying to hit each other. The chance of hitting is determined by a subtraction of the attacking character *precision* and the defending character *evasion*, each of which is composed of multiple variables.

```
 ToHit = Precision(a) - Evasion(b)
 Precision = Level(a) + Skill(a) + AttributeA(a) + AttributeB(a)
 Evasion   = Level(b) + AttributeB(b) + AttributeC(b) + Equipment(b)
```

I would to make sure that, given that the opponents are the same level, the result of `ToHit` should be between two known numbers.

I assume that there are infinite ways to achieve this. So let's say that I also know a few of the relationships between the variables.

So, we know that `Level(a) = Level(b)` so that's not an issue. The `Attribute` variables are variables that can be improved by the player each level. The player has 6 of these attributes, so there is 1/6 of a chance each level that he would improve `AttributeA`. We also know that Attributes cap out at 30, so tha maximum difference between two given attributes is always 29 (though smaller differences are more likely than larger differences).

`Skill` is also a variable in control of the player and function of the level. It is comprised between `0` and `100` though the curve of improving the skill has diminishing returns (i.e. it's easier to get from 0 to 50 than it is to get from 50 to 100).

Equipment is in my control, so I could balance out the equation by modifying this variable.

I really don't know where to start with this: I obviously can modify the equation to give each variable a different weight, but I would like a way to visualize the results and keep them consistent and predictable.

Any pointer is greatly appreciated (things I am missing, things I should research, faults in the way I approach the problem).

Comment: Just to clarify, the AttributeB in the calculation for precision is not necessarily the same as the AttributeB in Evasion?  If so, then you might want to express it as a function of a character, e.g. AttributeB(myGuy).

Comment: AttributeB is the same attribute but in the different characters, not sure if it makes sense to point it out, but I thought perhaps it would. I will edit it as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

In such games ToHit usually is a percentage and one could set

ToHit = Precision * Evasion

the probability to hit something as the product of precision and evasion. Precision and Evasion are also given as numbers in $[0,1]$. To construct such functions you could use linear approximation as follows. Set the probability to hit for a max level char to 99 % and for a min level char to 66 %.

$
Precsision(a) = ( \frac{0.33}{maxLevel- minLevel}(Level(a)-minLevel) + 0.66) * Skill(a) * AttributeA(a) * AttributeB(a)
$

The other unkown functions Skill, AttributeA and AttributeB you could model similarily.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very good pointer; I need to clarify, however, that the game I am talking about is a table-top one. For this reason, I would like to go for a Addition/Subtraction kind of approach, rather than for a Multiplication/Division since it is easier (and, most importantly, faster) for the average Joe to go with the former, than with the latter.

Comment: That makes sense. In table tops you usually use tables instead of formulas. Compare e.g. Warhammer Fantasy. You compare your Strength (e.g. 4) against their Toughness (e.g. 5) and then roll a dice D6. If the roll is larger than 5 you score a wound. Since you have to roll lots of dice (sometimes more than 20) formulase, even simple ones, do not seem to be practicable. To generate a table that can be memorized by the players is an art rather than science.

Comment: I was rather trying to simplify this system of table lookup; by having a Precision attribute and subtracting an Evasion you can roll against that number with a `d100`. The old **Stormbringer** used a similar system, as well as others RPG which don't come to my mind. The system worked, but the characters creation/advancement was much more predictable than the one I am building, hence I was wondering how to make the formula results more predictable, or maybe how would one visualize them in a graph for adjustment.